# Form not working after event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a form which dynamically appends the text to an unordered list in the HTML with a checkbox for marking as 'completed'. I can add multiple tasks, mark them as complete, but cannot continue after ANY checkbox has been marked. The console logs the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

I'm not sure what that error means as I can continue to add list items only until I've checked a checkbox.

```
// all jquery dom actions can only be called inside document ready.

function toDoList() {
    this.list = [];
}

function task(description) {
    this.description = description;
    this.completed = false;
}

toDoList.prototype.add = function (todo) {
    this.list.push(todo)
}

toDoList.prototype.complete = function (todo) {
    for (task in this.list) {
        if (this.list[task].description === todo) {
            this.list[task].completed = true
            console.log("Woot! You've completed: " + todo)
        } else {
            console.log("Couldn't find that task!")
        }
    }

}

var myList = new toDoList();
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#todoform").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var taskDescription = $("#todo").val()
        var myTask = new task(taskDescription)
        myList.add(myTask)
        $("#printout ul").append("<li class=\"task\"><input type=\"checkbox\">" + myTask.description + "</li>")
        $('#todo').val('');
        console.log(myList)
    });

    $('ul').delegate('.task', 'change', function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $(this).toggleClass("completed")
            var task = $(this).text()
            myList.complete(task)
            console.log(myList)
        }
    });

});
```

You can view my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/37811csy/):

Comment: paste  the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `for` loop in the `complete` handler, there you are using  a global reference to `task` as the loop variable, which is overriding the global `task`(the function) as a string. Then again when you say `new task()`, `task` is a string not a function which results in the error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

So make the `task` variable as a local one

```
for (var task in this.list) {}
```

Demo

```js
// all jquery dom actions can only be called inside document ready.

function ToDoList() {
  this.list = [];
}

function Task(description) {
  this.description = description;
  this.completed = false;
}

ToDoList.prototype.add = function(todo) {
  this.list.push(todo)
}

ToDoList.prototype.complete = function(todo) {
  for (var task in this.list) {
    if (this.list[task].description === todo) {
      this.list[task].completed = true
      console.log("Woot! You've completed: " + todo)
    } else {
      console.log("Couldn't find that task!")
    }
  }

}

var myList = new ToDoList();
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#todoform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var taskDescription = $("#todo").val()
    var myTask = new Task(taskDescription)
    myList.add(myTask)
    $("#printout ul").append("<li class=\"task\"><input type=\"checkbox\">" + myTask.description + "</li>")
    $('#todo').val('');
    console.log(myList)
  });

  $('ul').delegate('.task', 'change', function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
      $(this).toggleClass("completed")
      var task = $(this).text()
      myList.complete(task)
      console.log(myList)
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #D1D1D1
}
#todoform {
  margin: 5em auto 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
}
#printout {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1em auto 0 auto;
  color: black;
  text-indent: 1em;
}
#printout p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#printout p:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
#task {
  line-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form id="todoform" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" placeholder="Enter Your Todo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" id="addTodo" />
  </form>
  <div id="printout">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as a suggestion, since you are using both the `task` and `toDoList` as constructors, I would suggest to you start those names in capital letters like `Task` and `ToDoList`.

Comment: Good eye! Thanks Arun!